# Can't run jar file?

Tags: java, jar

I'm new to java so I might be missing something obvious.  I'm trying to create a simple command-line game in java.  I use two classes:

http://pastebin.com/wRgqgJQP

http://pastebin.com/0rXbxdiJ

The first handles user inputs, the second runs a math question game.
When I try to run the jar file (the eclipse file runs fine), I get an error - can't be launched, and the following console print out:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at game.GameHelper.getUserInput(GameHelper.java:12)
at game.MultGame.createGame(MultGame.java:18)
at game.MultGame.main(MultGame.java:12)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?  I'm thinking that the problem is related to using the sysout print thing...but Im not sure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` indicates that a variable was null when being used with either a `.` or an array reference like `[0]`.

The stack trace tells us it happened "at game.GameHelper.getUserInput(GameHelper.java:12)
".  Your source listing has this line at line 12 in GameHelper.

```
if (inputLine.length() == 0)
```

There is only one `.` telling us that `inputLine` was `null`.  How did that happen?  Well, it was assigned in line 11.

```
inputLine = is.readLine();
```

So. `readLine()` returned null.  How did that happen?  Well, from http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

> **Returns:** A String containing the contents of the line, not including
>   any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has
>   been reached

So the end of the stream has been reached.  The stream was constructed from System.in, so additional information is needed to tell why that may be.

Comment: ok, makes sense, thanks!  So if I understand right, the problem is that the program has decided the line has been read already, before any input is given?  How should I go about allowing the user to enter text?

Comment: No, that you have reached the end of the input stream.  This may be the case if you launch without a console window attached because then there is no place for the user to type text.  You must provide details of how you launch your program.

Answer (score 1):

The way to debug ANY nullpointerexception

1) Go to the line. 
2) Look at each method call on that line - is is possible that a method called on an object where the object is null ?

```
a=null ;
a.setX("X");

will result in a null pointer exception.
```

In your specific case, the line "if (inputLine.length() == 0)" is throwing a null pointer exception.  Thus, you should make sure that "inputLine" is not null ....

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason why you aren't using the Scanner class?

```
package game;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GameHelper {
    public String getUserInput(String prompt)
    {
        System.out.print(prompt + "  ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputline = scan.nextLine();
        return inputLine.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

And if all you ever want it to do is use the result to ParseInt, you could change

```
String inputLine = scan.nextLine()
```

to

```
int inputNumber = scan.nextInt()
```

and obviously change the return type from String to int

Comment: I guess...because I'd never heard of it until now?  haha.  I'll give it a try.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
package game;
import java.io.*;
public class GameHelper {

    public String getUserInput(String prompt) {
        String inputLine = null;
        System.out.print(prompt + "  ");
        try {
            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    System.in));
            inputLine = is.readLine();
            if (inputLine == null)
                return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
        }
        return inputLine.toLowerCase();
    }


}
```

To fix your other error surround

```
 numProbs=(Integer.parseInt(numProbsReader))
```

in try/catch so like this

```
try{
 numProbs=(Integer.parseInt(numProbsReader))
}catch(Exception e){System.err.println("Invalid Input");}
```

and that should help

Comment: thanks!  I did that, and the error is now: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417)  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at game.MultGame.createGame(MultGame.java:19)  at game.MultGame.main(MultGame.java:12)